# Correct order of Bootstrap Stylesheets

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The [Twitter Bootstrap API](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar) tells me to add my css to add padding to the body element in between the `bootstrap` css and the `bootstrap-responsive` css. I have done so in the `_master` file, but it doesn't seem to be adding the padding still.

Am I reading this incorrectly or could something else potentially be wrong?

**My `_master` head section**

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Get Bootstrapped</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/css/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/css/skin.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/css/bootstrap-responsive.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="~/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

**A visualization of the body padding not working (scrolled all the way to the top)**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to give a `padding-top: 40px` to the div which contains the body.

Ex: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P4YWT/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="padding-top: 40px">
        some content 1<br />
        some content 2<br />
        some content 3<br />
        some content 4<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I get for working on this stuff at 4am...this was the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use `padding-top: 40px` instead?